# ChartJS with Symfony 4.4 (UX component)

Tags: symfony, chart.js

As you might now, Symfony released some UX components some weeks ago. I'm trying to generate some charts using the Symfony UX ChartJs. Everything works as expected, but unfortunately, I understood that I'm not able to reproduce entire logic for `options` using only PHP and I have to rely on stimulus controllers to extend the behavior in order to achieve some extra behavior for the charts.

What I'm trying to achieve is to show percentage (%) symbol next to those numbers. I followed multiple tutorials from Stackoverflow, but there's no info for this component.

I created a new stimulus controller called `percentage_controller.js` and I have this code.

```
import {Controller} from 'stimulus';

export default class extends Controller {
    connect() {
        this.element.options = {
            tooltips: {
                enabled: false
            },
            plugins: {
                datalabels: {
                    formatter: (value, ctx) => {
                        return value.toFixed(2) + "%";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm rendering the chart using this line: `{{ render_chart(chart, {'data-controller': 'percentage'}) }}`.

Do you have any idea what's wrong and how I can achieve this behavior?

EDIT: I was able to find the answer. Please see it below!

Answer (score 2):

Here's the answer. Pretty close to @fbunhlak!

```
import {Controller} from 'stimulus';

export default class extends Controller {

connect() {
    this.element.addEventListener('chartjs:connect', this._onConnect);
}

_onConnect(event) {
    event.detail.chart.options.tooltips.callbacks.label = function (tooltipItem, data) {
        let label = data.labels[tooltipItem.index] || '';

        if (label) {
            label += ': ';
        }

        const sum = data.datasets[0].data.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue);
        const value = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];

        label += Number((value / sum) * 100).toFixed(2) + '%';

        return label;
    };
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this [example](https://github.com/symfony/ux-chartjs#extend-the-default-behavior)

```js
// mychart_controller.js

import { Controller } from 'stimulus';

export default class extends Controller {
    connect() {
        this.element.addEventListener('chartjs:connect', this._onConnect);
    }

    disconnect() {
        // You should always remove listeners when the controller is disconnected to avoid side effects
        this.element.removeEventListener('chartjs:connect', this._onConnect);
    }

    _onConnect(event) {
        event.detail.chart.options.plugins = {
            datalabels: {
                formatter: (value, ctx) => {
                    return value.toFixed(2) + "%";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it right now, but unfortunately is not working. :-/

Comment: Try to console.log anything to see if script is working.